# How do I use a PHP/MySQL-based script to ban IP blocks from a website?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a fairly large list of IPs and IP blocks that I'd like to ban. The list I have is done in blocks, currently in such a format:

```
1.2.3.4-1.2.3.54
5.6.7.8-5.6.7.8
2.3.4.5-2.3.4.116
```

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to block these IPs by somehow putting them into a MySQL database. I could, of course, separate all the blocks into separate IPs and put them in their own MySQL records, but that would be extremely inefficient with a large number of IPs. Blocking entire ranges, such as "1.2.3.*" would also result in unnecessarily banning a lot users.

Is there a way to do this effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the MySQL INET_ATON() and INET_NTOA() functions. Keep in mind these are MySQL specific, but you can implement them using php as well.

These functions convert an IP address from dot notation in to an integer. You can then store them in a table with "start_ip" and "end_ip" columns. When you are querying to see if an IP is banned, you can use a query with BETWEEN.

```
SELECT * FROM bans WHERE INET_ATON("127.0.0.1") BETWEEN start_ip AND end_ip
```

Comment: I am considering trying this for its simplicity. My only concern is that running the BETWEEN command on thousands of IP ranges, every time a page is loaded, would be too stressful. Would it be less stressful to use Truth's easier method?

Comment: With a proper index on the table, MySQL will be very efficient in finding rows that match the criteria, most likely quite a bit quicker than any other methods mentioned so far. You also won't need to process the IP to split it up in to 2 parts before doing the query. If you don't need any other information from the ban table, and the start_ip and end_ip columns are both covered by an index, you could very quickly determine if an IP is banned or not as MySQL would only need to access the index itself, instead of the data file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I did a few performance tests on a similar query. The table contained approx 2 million records. A query that returned ~40k results was executed in about 0.01 seconds. A query that returned a few results finished in 0.00 seconds, so I doubt you have anything to worry about in terms of performance.

Comment: One last point. I'm not sure if I misunderstood what you were saying, but you would only run the query once per page load. You would replace the 127.0.0.1 in the query above and replace it with the IP you are testing against.

Comment: I tried it out and it seems to be working perfectly--very quickly. This seems to be the optimal solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [netmasks](http://www.iplocation.net/tools/netmask.php)?

- 192.168.1.0/24 blocks 192.168.1.0 - 182.168.1.255
- 1.0.0.0/8 blocks 1.0.0.0 - 1.255.255.255

You only need 5 bytes for IPv4 addresses this way.  If you want to get crafty with your masking, make that 8 bytes.

This has the bonus of making comparisons very fast, by simply OR-ing the mask with the IP.  This is how IP routing works.

Also, you can use the MySQL functions [INET_NTOA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) and [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) to convert from a dot-formatted IP address to its numeric form, and back again, making storage efficient and easy to work with.

Comment: Probably a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a table like so:

```
range | start_number | end_number
------+--------------+-----------
```

Which will hold (for example): `1.2.3`, `4`, and `54` respectively.

Then you can easily check if a connecting IP address is within the range, and if the last section is between `start_number` and `end_number`.