# How do you update an IP block list from PHP when an invalid URL is accessed

Tags: php, .htaccess, block

I have clients with multiple websites on the same physical dedicated server.  Often, brute force attacks will try accessing invalid urls on one website and then continue on others.

Is there a way to capture invalid url requests on one website and update a shared block list for all the sites on the same server?

I read this: [How do I use a PHP/MySQL-based script to ban IP blocks from a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938865/how-do-i-use-a-php-mysql-based-script-to-ban-ip-blocks-from-a-website) and was looking for a way to update some kind of file I could auto-include on each site to reduce the hit of the malicious activities, perhaps cleaning that file on a cron.

Any thoughts or best practices for this kind of situation?

Thanks!

Comment: So if a legit visitor mistypes a URL or encounters a bad link they will be added to block list? Are you mixing up vulnerability scanners with brute force logins?

Comment: IP is meaningless, any one truly attacking with change ip's constantly.

Comment: Look at: http://www.fail2ban.org/

Comment: ^^ if your going that way, [PSAD](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/) is an idea also

Comment: @Dagon: actually banning by IP is pretty efficient for small-to-medium projects. fail2ban successfully helps with http and ssh brute forces

Comment: What I do when I do the block is a different matter, it's the ability to share the information in a sensible way that's of most concern. In this case, most users should be logged in and that's caught in a different way. Public url scanning is the issue I'm concerned with examining. @Dagon, I'm concerned with stopping the whole process so it doesn't continue across multiple sites. I'm well aware of the ip volatility issue.

Comment: This is a bad idea, for the reasons already mentioned.  In any case, you haven't told us how you are blocking these IPs, so it isn't possible to help you anyway.

Comment: The 2nd to last line says: "Any thoughts or best practices..." so I'm open to what the right way should be in case you happened to have one in mind? The IPs are detected with PHP (tagged in the question) as having accessed an invalid url, captured by a front-controller, which the decides what to do (logged in users are redirected to appropriate pages - logged out users access invalid url types, e.g. ../../ etc/passwd, and a lot of others have the IPs currently written to a DB table for later analysis.) A better solution is sought.  Does that help?

Comment: Votes to close should be accompanied by a reason. This is a request to address a problem related to others that have been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have serious reservations about it, our server admin installed [PSAD](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/), which 'seems' to work - lots of alerts about the Chinese (China based IP addresses, with a proxy that could of course be any one anywhere) at the moment. Just be clear that you know what you are blocking and why.

TIP: set alert level to 4+ for email alerts (or just turn email alerts off) or you get thousands a day.

Comment: I have a specific use case for removing known sequential behaviour of annoying scripts, so it's a short-term simple fix for a simple problem and not a recommendation for anything else.  This probably will help in our case. Thanks!

Comment: well it is of course your call, all the best.

Answer (score 2):

If you have server access, I would recommend using Fail2ban (http://www.fail2ban.org). If you don't have server access, you could create a redirect in the .htaccess file to a PHP script that logs the number of bad requests and blocks the IP after a certain threshold (for example, 10 requests). However, it's much better to handle this at the server level so that Apache doesn't have to handle all these requests.

Best regards.

Comment: I have access to the server at a root equivalent level, however I'm looking for something that can be shared across each site.  I think fail2ban would require retrospective analysis from what I can see.

Comment: if each site is on the same sever both psad and fail2ban can access multiple logs

Comment: PSAD looks like a good solution - can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use something like this:

Lets assume your have only assigned the following links to be accessed.

Suppose your have normally a url something like `site.com/index.php?id=`so, if you want people only to access `id=homepage` or `about-us`, `service`,`contact`

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
switch($id){

case "homepage";
echo //do something
break;

case "about-us";
include('about.php');
break;

case "service"; 
echo  //something;
break;

case "contact";
echo //something
break;



default: 
get_ip_and_ban(); // initiate a function, that records and bans IP
break; 


}
```

---

UPDATED - ( How to share IP across multiple servers..) or something along the lines

Ok, this is how to get the IP.. or how I would get the IP.

```
function get_ip() {

    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) 
        { $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; }
            elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR']))
                {$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'];}
                    else {$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}
                        return $ip;

}
```

So, `get_ip();` is a function that gets the ip, now, with this you can insert into database anyone trying to access bad links. So, after having done that let us create a simple function that checks if the bad IP exists in database. suppose `$allowed_ip` is an array of bad IPs from database and this function will check if one of the bad IP exists, and if it does the following function will block the user from accessing the page.

```
function access_directive($allowed_ip){

    if(get_ip() === $allowed_ip)
     {exit("Dude, You are blocked. Get Lost"); }

}
```

Now for the purpose of simplicity, I will try to only block localhost which is
 `<?php echo access_directive("127.0.0.1"); ?>` at the top of your page, and will block any IP that is indicated inside the `access_direcive();`

You need to create a database for storing bad ip, then use the above function or something like it, at the top of your page to block other people.

Comment: This adequately describes the situation, but what I was looking for was a way to share the results of the ban across multiple sites on the same server, or potentially others would be nice.  How would you do that to extend your example?

Comment: @MyStream I have updated it, you can check

Comment: That would work from PHP. Would you be able to do that at the htaccess level or before beginning the processing of PHP scripts?

Comment: Just put it at the top of your code, since you probably need to block everyone with the bad IP from every page.